# Whats a scala-like way to alter first and last in a List

Tags: scala

I have a List[String] that com.github.seratch.scalikesolr is populating a little inconveniantly...
If List has one element, it looks like this:

```
[value]
```

(It has prepended and appended brackets).

If List has more than 1 element, the elements look like:

```
[value1
value2]
```

Struggling to find clean looking scala-ish code to remove the brackets if present.
what do you suggest. thanks in advance.

P.S. I have several Lists to apply this "filter" to... so reusable code is the better approach.

Comment: Is the result `List("[value1 value2"])` or `List("[value1", "value2])`?

Comment: Sorry should have been clearer. Lists look like:   List("[value1", "value2]")

Comment: Can the `value` itself contain a bracket? If not, the simplest solution would be just to replace brackets with empty strings.

Comment: The values would never normally contain leading "[" nor trailing "]".

Comment: Also, can we assume that only the first and the last element contain the bracket? Or, even more precise: Are we safe to assume that, if the list contains more than 1 element, the first gets a leading "[" and the last contains a trailing "]"?

Comment: Can you just fix the code where the list is created? Looks like that's the source of the problem...

Comment: problem is created by com.github.seratch.scalikesolr. The author has denied my request to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def deBracketize(list: List[String]): List[String] = list.map(_.stripPrefix("[").stripSuffix("]"))
```

Example usage:

```
println(deBracketize(List("[value1", "value2]")))
println(deBracketize(List("[value1]")))
```

Outputs:

```
List(value1, value2)
List(value1)
```

Comment: winner due to succinctness

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
def removeBrackets(list: List[String]): List[String] = list.size match {
  case 0|1 => list.map(_.stripPrefix("[").stripSuffix("]"))
  case _ => (list.head.stripPrefix("[") :: list.drop(1).dropRight(1)) :+ list.last.stripSuffix("]")
}
```

Comment: If List size is zero, why would I take any action but return the empty list?

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_65).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def stripBrackets(str: String) = str.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "")

def stripBrackets(ls: List[String]): List[String] =
  ls match {
    case Nil => ls
    case List(head) => List(stripBrackets(head))
    case List(head, last) => List(stripBrackets(head), stripBrackets(last))
    case _ => stripBrackets(ls.head) :: ls.take(ls.size - 1).drop(1) ::: (stripBrackets(ls.last) :: Nil)
  }

val singleElemList = List("[value1]")
val twoElemList = List("[value1", "value2]")
val multiElemList = List("[value1", "value2", "value3", "value4]")

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

stripBrackets: (str: String)String <and> (ls: List[String])List[String]
stripBrackets: (str: String)String <and> (ls: List[String])List[String]
singleElemList: List[String] = List([value1])
twoElemList: List[String] = List([value1, value2])
multiElemList: List[String] = List([value1, value2, value3, value4])

scala> stripBrackets(singleElemList)
res0: List[String] = List(value1)

scala> stripBrackets(twoElemList)
res1: List[String] = List(value1, value2)

scala> stripBrackets(multiElemList)
res2: List[String] = List(value1, value2, value3, value4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in a functional style using an optional parameter.

```
def removeBracket(list: List[String], first: Int=1): List[String] =
  list match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case a::Nil => List(a.substring(first,a.length-1))
    case a::q => a.substring(first,a.length)::removeBracket(q,0)
  }
```

Test:

```
scala> removeBracket(Nil)
res1: List[String] = Nil
scala> removeBracket(List("[test]"))
res1: List[String] = List("test")
scala> removeBracket(List("[test","tist]"))
res1: List[String] = List("test","tist")
scala> removeBracket(List("[test","toast","tist]"))
res1: List[String] = List("test","toast","tist")
```

Answer (score -1):

List("[value1", "value2]").map{_.replace("[","").replace("]","")}